# \def two macros with same name, but different argument syntax

Tags: macros, tex-core

Is it possible to have macros with the same name, but different “syntax”?

E.g. we have the primitive [`\font`](http://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html#font-ai) which could be seen as having 3 arguments(a. without size information; b. giving the fontsize with `at`; c. giving scaling information with `scaled`).

Is there a way to provide similar functionality for own macros?

I already tried the following (stupid) experiment:

```
\def\print#1at#2,#3{The text ``#1'' shall be printed at $#2 \abovewithdelims()0pt #3$}
\def\print#1by#2,#3{The text ``#1'' shall be printed by #2 and #3 Doe}

\print{Testtext}at 2,3

\print{Testtext}by{Jon},{Jane}

\bye
```

Trying to compile it (using `tex -interaction=nonstopmode def.tex`) yields following error:

```
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=tex)
(./def.tex
Runaway argument?
{Testtext}at 2,3 
! Paragraph ended before \print was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.5 

[1] )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on def.dvi (1 page, 280 bytes).
Transcript written on def.log.
```

Comment: No: each `\def` has exactly one argument definition. If we can assume that `#1` is well-formed then this is, though, quite doable using `\futurelet` (cf. LaTeX's optional argument syntax): can we assume that `#1` is always a `<balanced text>`?

Comment: I've tagged here as [tag:tex-core] rather than [tag:plain-tex] as the question is applicable to any TeX format.

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware of ht tex-core-tag, I had chosen it if I was… Also what exactly do mean by “balanced text”?

Comment: No problem on the tagging: these things are not always easy. On `<balanced text>`: if you are going to ask low-level TeX questions then it's likely some things will be 'taken as read' :-) A `<balanced text>` is either a single token or multiple tokens enclosed in a pair of (usually) braces (matching/balanced pairs of catcode-1/catcode-2 tokens required). Examples: `a`, `\foo`, `{}`, `{Hello {world} }` but not `{}}`, _etc._

Comment: OK, so my first intuition on this was right :) And of course param `#1` is meant to be a single token or balanced group. Now it is time to dig into @david-carlisle's answer and understand whats going on, then I can accept it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

An individual macro may only have one definition, but a combination of macros can parse the input stream:

```
\def\aprint#1at#2,#3{The text ``#1'' shall be printed at $#2 \abovewithdelims()0pt #3$}
\def\bprint#1by#2,#3{The text ``#1'' shall be printed by #2 and #3 Doe}


\def\print#1#2{\csname#2print\endcsname{#1}#2}

\print{Testtext}at 2,3

\print{Testtext}by{Jon},{Jane}

\bye
```